# Substitute a value only when greater than

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Trying to substitute a value in a number of files using shell commands (to use in a script to iterate over the files in a directory).

```
Input file examples:

file1:
019=False
051=Limited
051>Limited Lease Time=2419200

file2:
019=False
051=Limited
051>Limited Lease Time=14400
```

This worked okay:

```
sed -e '/Limited Lease Time=/s/[0-9]\+$/86400/g' <infile >outfile

# cat outfile
019=False
051=Limited
051>Limited Lease Time=86400
```

But ... then realised that I was replacing any value, including ones lower than 86400, when I only want to replace anything greater than 86400.

I thought I could use awk, and this 'kind of' worked, as in the output was only 'Limited Lease Time' lines that has a value > 86400:

```
awk -F= '/Limited Lease Time/ && $2 > 86400 { print $2 }'
```

But ... it's only outputing the matched line, whereas I need the original output (3 lines in the examples), including the modification, if the matched value > 86400.

Appreciate some advice on a way to handle this !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `=` field-separator in `Awk` and get lines in `$2` greater than the value you have set,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $0 ~ /\<Limited Lease Time\>/ && $2 > 86400 {$2=86400}1' file
```

For an input-file,

```
cat file
019=False
051=Limited
051>Limited Lease Time=14400
051>Limited Lease Time=94400
051>Limited Time=14400
```

Running the command produces output as you needed.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $0 ~ /\<Limited Lease Time\>/ && $2 > 86400 {$2=86400}1' file
019=False
051=Limited
051>Limited Lease Time=14400
051>Limited Lease Time=86400
051>Limited Time=14400
```

Also you can make it configurable by using the `-v` variable import in `Awk`

```
awk -v thresh=86400 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $0 ~ /\<Limited Lease Time\>/ && $2 > thresh {$2=thresh}1' file
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks ! Used the awk line with the '-v' variable import to make it cleaner in my script. Thank you. Just off now to read the man page and work out exactly what it does ;-)